# Multiple MySQL database to One database - Bidirectional

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-replication, database-administration

So I have a scenario here. I have a requirement which needs both Offline and Online option. When it comes to Online, the app should also be managed by the central admin. So, I have an offline app in 10 different locations. Each one has its own database say DB1, DB2, DB3, etc with the same structure.

1. Once an app comes Online, I would like to merge it into one central database when they come online.
2. Once let's say DB1 is merged with a central database, I will make changes in a central database(where I have an app to make changes).
3. When changes are done in the central app, I would like it to reflect the changes in the respective small database.

My question here is,

1. Do I need to merge 10 small databases into one? Is this a correct approach?
2. How to make changes to the respective databases through the central app?

Comment: In general, you should have just one logical database per application.  It will be very complicated to try to sync multiple databases.  Maybe add more description about the problem and why you think this is necessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for your reply. I have a requirement which needs both Offline and Online option. When it comes to Online, the app should also be managed by the central admin. I hope it clears!

Comment: Move to dba.stackexchange.com.